# What is the unconditional distribution?

Tags: conditional-expectation

Suppose that Θ is a random variable that follows a gamma distribution with parameters λ and α, where α is an integer, and suppose that, conditional on Θ, X follows a Poisson distribution with parameter Θ. Find the unconditional distribution of α + X (Hint : Find the mgf by using iterated conditional expectations.

please answer..

Comment: How do you define this particular gamma distribution?  There are a couple of different parameterizations of it, and I don't generally see them with the parameters being called $\lambda$ and $\alpha$; so, I'm not sure which one you're getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You're asked to consider the *moment generating function* of $\alpha+X$, which is
$$
M_{\alpha+X}(t):=\mathbb{E}[e^{t(\alpha+X)}].
$$
Because $\alpha$ is constant, we can write
$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{t(\alpha+X)}]=\mathbb{E}[e^{t\alpha}\cdot e^{tX}]=e^{t\alpha}\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]=e^{t\alpha}M_X(t).
$$
So, we really just need to compute $M_X(t)$ to finish the problem.

Now, we know that conditioned on $\Theta$, $X\sim\text{Poisson}(\Theta)$; using this, you can show fairly easily that
$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}\mid\Theta]=\exp[\Theta(e^t-1)].
$$
However, we know that
$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[E^{tX}\mid\Theta]],
$$
so that
$$
M_X(t)=\mathbb{E}[\exp[\Theta(e^t-1)]]
$$
where this last expectation is taken with respect to $\Theta$.

Comment: Thanks. 
then, unconditional distribution of α + X is exp(tα)expectation(exp(Θ(exp(t)-1))) ?
I'm not understanding mean of unconditional dist.
unconditional dist is equal to m.g.f ?

Comment: No; that is it's moment generating function, though.

Comment: Please tell me technique (distribution from moment generating function.)

Comment: In this sort of problem: you should find that the moment generating function corresponds to a known (common) probability distribution.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm learning basic mathematical statistics.. very very difficult. I'll try it !!
Thanks :)